# Image Uploading to Cloud Storage with firebase functions Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload a base64 jpeg image to Firebase Storage I don't know what's wrong. I don't think the error is from my image encoding.
I'm trying to upload an image from the user's phone to the firebase storage using React Native (fetch API) to send the request.

index.js file:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });
const fs = require("fs");
const UUID = require("uuid-v4");

const gcconfig = {
projectId: "awsome-34343434343434",
keyFileName: "awsome.json"
};

 const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const storage = new Storage(gcconfig);

exports.storeImage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
cors(request, response, () => {
console.log("THE BODY:" + JSON.stringify(request.body));

const body = JSON.parse(request.body);
console.log("THE IMAGE:" + body.image);
fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/uploaded-image.jpg", body.image, "base64", err => {
  console.log(err);
  return response.status(500).json({ error: err });
});
const bucket = storage.bucket("awsome-1548769019561");
const uuid = UUID();
console.log("UUID: " + uuid);
bucket.upload(
  "/tmp/uploaded-image.jpg",
  {
    uploadType: "media",
    destination: "/places/" + uuid + ".jpg",
    metadata: {
      metadata: {
        contentType: "image/jpeg",
        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
      }
    }
  },
  (err, file) => {
    if (!err) {
      response.status(201).json({
        imageUrl:
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" +
          bucket.name +
          "/o/" +
          encodeURIComponent(file.name) +
          "?alt=media&token=" +
          uuid
      });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      response.status(500).json({ error: err });
    }
    }
  );
});
});
```

the request body I sent :

```
{"image": "/9j/4QG1RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwEQA..."}
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at Object.parse (native)
at cors (/user_code/index.js:21:24)
at cors (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
at /user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
at originCallback (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15)
at /user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
at optionsCallback (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
at corsMiddleware (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
at exports.storeImage.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:18:3)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
```

Comment: FYI you should not need to provide a configuration to the Cloud Storage SDK.  If you initialize it with no parameters, it will use the default service account for your project, which should have all the access you need to your Cloud Storage buckets.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is being caused by the line `const body = JSON.parse(request.body);`

Firebase automatically parses data from the request body, there's no need for you to try to do it yourself, see the section "*Read values from the request*" in the [function calls docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events). Since your body is already in JSON format, and your function is trying to re-JSON-ify it... then it triggers that error. Take out that line and you shouldn't get that error anymore.